# Change CSS with Nullish Coalescing operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

*New to Javascript

The code below is a section that changes the image source to the saved one.

**Desired result:** When there is no source for the image I want to display a 'default.jpg' image.

Perhaps, is there another way to write this logic out as a simple(r) condition?

Attempt

```js
  set_image({
    image_data_url: items.image_data_url ?? "",
    image_filename: items.image_filename ?? image.src = './assets/default.jpg',
  });
```

Current

```js
  set_image({
    image_data_url: items.image_data_url ?? "",
    image_filename: items.image_filename ?? "No Image",
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
set_image({
  image_data_url: items.image_data_url ?? "",
  image_filename: items.image_filename ?? './assets/default.jpg',
});
```

Comment: Yeah... smh. I wasn't paying attention at all. I was trying to 'show' an image, instead I was showing nothing but the filename of the 'default.jpg' image I wanted to show. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to show default image for "No image found"
Please comment if any query.

for this

**1) First Option : - use onerror**

```
<img id="currentPhoto" src="https://www.ccrharrow.org/Images/content/953/741209.pg" onerror="this.src='https://www.unesale.com/ProductImages/Large/notfound.png'" alt="">
```

**2)use addeeventlistner**,

```
img.addEventListener('error', function handleError() {

    const defaultImage =
      'https://bobbyhadz.com/images/blog/javascript-show-div-on-select-option/banner.webp';

    img.src = defaultImage;
    img.alt = 'default';
  });
```

**3)use alt fot just text** if you want to show text then use alt attribut for img tag.

**4)Nullish Coalescing operator** is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined

```
    var defaultImage = 'image1.png';
    var noimage = 'noimagefound.png';
    img.src = defaultImage ?? noimage;
```